# Everytime i tried something in console like sudo apt-get install build-essential i get all this! I dont know how to fix it it stucks here

Tags: updates, update-manager

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.2.0-79-generic-pae
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 114 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 525879 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.2.0-79-generic-pae (3.2.0-79.115) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-79-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-79-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-79-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-79-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-79-generic-pae
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
```

Comment: I don't see any real errors aside from the message that there are "3 not fully installed or removed". How long have you waited since it has been stuck like this?

Comment: I have waited hours!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to fix the issue and the post any errors.

First, run the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Again, please post any errors. Thanks!

Comment: @dianesis If any errors arise or this doesn't work update your question with information about what happened after you tried that. Even if it just plain didn't work.

Comment: problem is nothing happens after hours

Comment: after i issue this command  sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  ...
Then it just says Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic